# References for Topology with applications in Engineering, Computer Science, Robotics

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, algebraic-topology, topological-data-analysis

I am reading a book on motion planning for mobile robots, I have a really hard time with the mathematics. Some parts it is talking about the topology of the space and manifolds and compactness of the space.... I am too lost. I also have some problems with the math notations used in this book. There is an appendix which goes through topology and manifolds but it's only 3 pages and it really fast.

I need a very basic book or paper about topology, which I can read in about a month. Something very basic and with some real applications.

Any other comments are highly appreciated.

Edit:
I ***think*** I will need to have a basic idea about:
-  Topology
-  Manifolds
-  Group theory
-  Homology

I have found some basic books on topology. Would you take a look at them and let me know which one would be more appropriate for me?
1- [Topology for Computing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521136091)
2- [Computational Topology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821849255)
3- [Elementary Applied Topology](http://hans.math.upenn.edu/~ghrist/notes.html)
4- [Topology and Robotics (Contemporary Mathematics)](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=CONM-438), I think this one would be great if I have some basic idea about topology

Comment: I think it would be more efficient for you to go to the mathematics department and find a topologist who's willing to explain the relevant parts to you.

Comment: You'll presumably need to know some algebra too (notably group theory), as I imagine the braid groups may play a prominent role in your study.

Comment: What's the robotics book? My suggestion is to get another book, unless there's something very special about the current one.

Comment: @Raskolnikov First I prefer to read a book about topology, and if I had a problem I could find a topologist in my university.

Comment: @DanielRust I think you are right. Because in some papers I have seen something about group theory. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @bubba I really have to read this book and understand it.

Comment: @Ali I think it really depends on your background. As a pure mathematician, my tastes for a 'good topology book' might differ from those of a engineer. Do you have a suitably strong background in pure mathematics (particularly proof based subjects)?

Comment: It sounds like only certain parts are giving you trouble. Depending on how many parts and how much trouble you're having, you could simply ask specific questions here at m.SE.

Comment: @DanielRust I am not great at following the proofs, but I am not that bad. If the text is written for engineers I would not have any problems. Actually I want a book with some real applications and proofs together.

Comment: @rghthndsd I prefer to read a basic and elementary book on Topology first. I want to do my PhD in the same topic and I know I will need a strong background.

Comment: @AlexanderFrei: I've just tidied up by deleting a few no-longer-relevant comments that were addressed to you.

Comment: @JW: I havedeleted mine, too. Best regards, Alex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As usrtt1 suggests, [Introduction to Topology: Pure and Applied](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131848690) by Adams and Franzosa is a great book introducing topology and many of its applications, although it stops short of material based on homology. An alternative might be Basener's [Topology and Its Applications](http://people.rit.edu/wfbsma/topology_and_its_applications/textbook.html), based on its table of contents, but I do not have the latter book.

There are many abstract algebra texts out there. One place to pick up some basic group theory would be Fraleigh's [A First Course in Abstract Algebra, 7th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201763907), as this edition contains a light introduction to homology.

Some good suggestions for further reading can be found on [Jeff Erickson's list of references for his Computational Topology course](http://compgeom.cs.uiuc.edu/%7Ejeffe/teaching/comptop/reading.html). In addition, once you have a fairly strong background in topology and manifolds, Farber's small book: [Invitation to Topological Robotics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/303719054X) could be of interest.

---

Update 1: Michael Robinson's [Topological Signal Processing](http://www.springer.com/engineering/signals/book/978-3-642-36103-6), published in 2014, is an introduction to the use of topological tools and sheaves in signal processing. See also [Robinson's website](http://www.drmichaelrobinson.net/).

Update 2: Nicholas A. Scoville's [Discrete Morse Theory](https://bookstore.ams.org/stml-90), published in 2019, is a very accessible introduction to the titular topic. No group theory required, just some linear algebra.

---

Edit re the four books mentioned in the question:

*Topology for Computing* and *Computational Topology* are well worth reading, but might move a little fast for the beginner. However, once you've picked up some basic topology and group theory, they should be much more accessible.

Robert Ghrist's *Elementary Applied Topology* is intentionally "a quick tour...to motivate...applied topology," according to the author. Ghrist moves swiftly through a dizzying array of topological concepts and applications. It's wonderful inspiration to dive deeper into this material.

As for *Topology and Robotics*, I do not have this particular book, but it looks like a collection of papers, probably best approached when you have a fairly strong background. You may wish to check the authors' homepages for preprints.

Answer (score 4):

There's a really good book on topology in engineering mentioned by the others too:

Introduction to Topology - Pure and Applied, by Colin Adams and Robert Franzosa

The nice thing about this textbook is that it gives a detailed application to the concepts after every chapter:

1. Introduction
2. Topological Basis -> Mutation of DNA
3. Closure, Interior and Boundary -> Data in GIS
4. Creation of Spaces -> Configuration and Phase Space
5. Continuity -> Robotics
6. Metric Spaces
7. Connectedness -> Automated Guided Vehicles
8. Compactness
9. Dynamical Systems -> Chaos in Population Model
10. Homotopy -> Heartbeat Model
11. Fixed Point Theorem -> Economics
12. Embeddings -> Digital Image Processing
13. Knots -> Chirality in Biochemistry
14. Graphs -> Boiling Point of Molecules, Electronic Circuits
15. Manifolds -> Geometry of the Universe

For a more detailed table of contents, see http://math.umaine.edu/~franzosa/TOC.htm.

Answer (score 2):

I have not read this: [http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Topology-Applied-Colin-Adams/dp/0131848690/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131848690) but I heard good things about it!